# Random Variables in Batch Files

Tags: random, batch-file

I am trying to create a random variable between 0 and 3 with a batch file. Right now I have the following code:

```
@echo off
set /a var=%random%/8192
@echo %var%
Pause
```

This batch file returns "2" every time. If I type the same commands into the command line directly it returns 0 through 3.

Any related knowledge would be appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not having this problem. Try taking out the `@` before `@echo %var%`? Though that really shouldn't change anything...

Comment: Your code generate a random number between 0 and 3; the right formula would be: `set /a var=%random%/6554`. However, the _standard_ formula is much clearer (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: I changed my answer because the OP changed his question: originally the range of desired random numbers was 0 to 4...

The right formula is:

```
set /a var=%random% * 4 / 32768
```

The use of other operators instead (like / or %) modify random number distribution, so you will get a repeated result more frequently than with the right formula.

**EDIT**: *Additional explanations added*

Previous code should correctly works in your example above. However, if your code is placed inside a *code block* (enclosed in parentheses), then you must use Delayed Expansion (as other people indicated in their answers) in *all* variables that may be modified inside the block, including RANDOM. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:ProgStart
(
set /a var = !random! * 4 / 32768
goto target!var!
)
```

If you wish, you may use this simpler formula that gives equivalent results (random numbers between 0 and 3):

```
set /a var = !random! / 8192
```

Comment: It's 4 not 5, and 32768 / 4 =8192.  His command is correct, just in a reduced form.

Comment: @rojo: The Op wants "to create a random variable between 0 and 4", and "%RANDOM% - expands to a random decimal number between 0 and 32767" (taken from `set /?`). This mean that %random%/8192 produce a random number between 0 and 3 (try it: `set /a 32767/8192`).

Comment: you're correct, of course.  Sorry about that.  I've got a toddler climbing on me at the moment and can't update my answer.  If you agree with my explanation about why his code has different results when executed via cmd versus batch script, feel free to copy / paste from my answer so at least one answer on this blasted thread will address all the problems demonstrated by the op.  :)  +1 in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The actual command you want is:

```
set /a var=%random% %% 4
```

This will give you: 0, 1, 2 or 3.

If you are doing this inside a FOR-loop use !..!-type variable instead of %..%-type variables in which case you will also need `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` somewhere near the beginning of your batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you use %random% inside an `if` or `for` code block. In this case you need `delayed expansion` and !variables! instead of %variables%. Example:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    echo %random% !random!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modulo works pretty well in this situation:

```
set /a ran=%random% %% 4 + 1
```

Would set `%ran%` to a number between 1 and 4. However, that only works in a batch file.

On the command prompt, you would need:

```
set /a num=%random% % 4 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.  I have a suspicion though.  In your full script, do you `set var` and check its value within a `for` loop or `if` statement?  If so, when you check the value of `%var%` the result is whatever your script inherited as the environment variable `%var%`'s value, probably a holdover from your command line testing outside the script.

If my assessment is true, then you need a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `echo !var!`.  Otherwise `for` or `if` will evaluate `%var%` with the value it contained at the time `for` or `if` was first encountered.

Comment: Yes I do use Var with if statements later on in my code but with this change I am still getting the same problem. Am I implementing this correctly?

    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    :ProgStart
    set /a var = !random!/8192
    if !var!==0 goto target0
    if !var!==1 goto target1
    if !var!==2 goto target2
    if !var!==3 goto target3

Comment: @user2053067: May I invite you to review my answer?... Thanks